# SharePoint Client web part iframe

Tags: css, iframe, sharepoint-online

I am trying to make a simple add-in to sharepoint online with some pictures.
But all the pictures is not showing beacuse the iframe is defualt set to 300x200px in sharepoint and i canr acces it from visualstudio, but i can change the height in the browser window to get it to work. So is there a way with CODE and not in the edit webpart page that can change the size of the "box" the content is in?

this is how it looks now.

[image]

this is how i want it to look.
[image]